# Java, инструменты для парсинга текстового файла

Tags: java

Задача в следующем:
Требуется из текстового файла большого объема удалять персональные данные (например IP адреса), подскажите библиотеку/метод для парса .txt файлов большого объема. 
Аналогично jsoup, только для .txt )

Comment: HTML - это формат текстовых данных, так что Jsoup тоже парсит **текстовые** файлы. В каком формате записаны ваши данные?

Comment: для этого можно использовать регулярные выражения!

Comment: Текстовый формат

Answer (score -2):

1. StringTokenizer
2. Scanner
3. Pattern
4. String#split(...)

Нашел вот такие варианты

Comment: я не уверен - это ответ (если да, то стоит расписать его до полноценного решения)? или дополнение к вопросу?